# URL based Javascript to show all variables in the page

Tags: javascript, address-bar

I've seen javascript (and written some too) to show the contents of input tags (useful if the guy before you left a password in an input...), but I want to use JS to show the Javascript variables that exist in the page.

The reason I want to do this is because I want to check out a file sharing site to see if it's real or just a rootkit hotbed.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about javascript injection to gain the value of a specific input, or listing out all inputs on the page?

Comment: Well, once I see all of the values, I can prbably just use a *javascript: var = val*, right? I'm asking how to list all of the variables by name so I can change the necessary ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are DOM inspectors in both IE and FF. In older IE versions you'll want the [Document Tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee371264%28Expression.30%29.aspx) section of their [Web Developer Accessories](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/previous/webaccess/webdevaccess.mspx). In IE8 there go to Tools->Developer Tools and there you have a nice little console to play with that will show you these things. In FF you can use the built in DOM inspector or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (my personal favourite). There is also this [bookmarklet](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html#view%5Fvariables), here is the code (cleaned up):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var wer = "asdasd";

            function getEm()
            {
                var x,d,i,v,st;
                x=open();
                d=x.document;
                d.open();

                function hE(s)
                {
                    s=s.replace(/&/g,"&amp;");
                    s=s.replace(/>/g,"&gt;");
                    s=s.replace(/</g,"&lt;");
                    return s;
                }

                d.write("<style>td{vertical-align:top; white-space:pre; } table,td,th { border: 1px solid #ccc; } div.er { color:red }</style><table border=1><thead><tr><th>Variable</th><th>Type</th><th>Value as string</th></tr></thead>");

                for (i in window)
                {
                    if (!(i in x) )
                    {
                        v=window[i];
                        d.write("<tr><td>" + hE(i) + "</td><td>" + hE(typeof(window[i])) + "</td><td>");
                        if (v===null)
                            d.write("null");
                        else if (v===undefined)
                            d.write("undefined");
                        else
                            try
                            {
                                st=v.toString();
                                if (st.length)
                                    d.write(hE(v.toString()));
                                else
                                    d.write("%C2%A0")
                            }
                            catch(er)
                            {
                                d.write("<div class=er>"+hE(er.toString())+"</div>")
                            }

                        d.write("</pre></td></tr>");
                    }
                }

                d.write("</table>");
                d.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="getEm()">
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this [view-variables](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/webdevel.html#view_variables) bookmarklet.